# I am trying to send 1000+ http requests to my server using JMeter

Tags: csv, http, jmeter, request

i have created a csv file that contains all the http request logs. I want to run them all at the same time. Is this possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is.

1. Add [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test Plan and set the number of threads to be equal to the number of lines in your CSV file:

   [image]

   this way JMeter will execute all the requests **once**, if you want to execute them more than once or use a "pool" of 1000 users to execute all the requests from the file - amend the configuration accordingly
2. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) to the Thread Group and provide the location of your CSV file there. Also provide a JMeter Variable reference name so you could re-use it later on, i.e. `URL` would be a good choice:

   [image]
3. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to your Thread Group and put `${URL}` into "Path" field:

   [image]

The approach will work if:

- your CSV file looks like:

  ```
  http://example.com/somepath
  http://example.org/someother/path
  etc.
  ```
- you need to send only [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) requests